# whereBetween Dates in laravel 4 eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query like that

```
SELECT * FROM `sp_price` WHERE (`from_date` between '2014-08-15' and '2014-09-18') || (`to_date` between '2014-08-15' and '2014-09-18')
```

Now how I can convert this query in `laravel 4`. I use `Eloquent`

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 18):

```
DB::table(sp_price)
     ->whereBetween('from_date',array('2014-08-15','2014-08-18'))
     ->orWhereBetween('to_date',array('2014-08-15','2014-08-15'))
     ->get();
```

maybe you can try this

Comment: how can I build this    `select * from calendar_schedules as cs where 1446377416 between cs.from_booking_date and cs.to_booking_date;`

Comment: Here is what that works : `$schedule = DB::table('calendar_schedules')
                ->whereRaw('(? between `from_booking_date` and `to_booking_date`) OR (? between `from_booking_date` and `to_booking_date`)',[$request->input('startDate'),$request->input('endDate')])
                ->first();`

Answer (score 4):

```
  $count =  TokenLog::whereBetween(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), [$start_date, $end_date])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're checking both `from_date` and `to_date` for the same range of dates...if this will always be the case, you can make this query a bit more "eloquent":

In the **SpPrice.php** model:

```
public function getPriceByDate($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    $range = [$fromDate, $toDate];
    return $this
        ->whereBetween('from_date', $range)
        ->orwhereBetween('to_date', $range)
        ->get();
}
```

Then, to call this method from a controller:

```
    $prices = new SpPrice;
    $price = $prices->getPriceByDate('2014-08-15', '2014-09-18');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereRaw()` to add a raw where clause to the query, for example:

```
$results = SpPrice::whereRaw("('2014-08-15' between `from_date` and `to_date`) || ('2014-09-18' between `from_date` and `to_date`)")->get();
```

Or maybe you can use `DB::raw()` as first argument of `whereBetween()`, but I'm not sure if it's possible, in that case you can use `orWhere()` with a closure to write a more *readable* code, for example:

```
SpPrice::whereBetween(DB::raw('"2014-08-15"'), ['from-date', 'to_date'])->orWhere(function($q)
{
    $q->whereBetween(DB::raw('"2014-09-18"'), ['from-date', 'to_date']);
});
```

But I'm not quite sure if this works, give it a try.