# WhereBetween not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel framework but in this WhereBetween not working. i am using price range where price starts form 1 to 500. when i set price 1-100
it gives me all the records that is in beetween 1 to 100 i.e. 20,40,50 etc. When i change the value from 1- 150 the above result will not be displayed it gives me no result(20,40,50). Can anyone help me . Here is my Code

```
enter code here

     $products = Product::with("productimages")
                ->whereBetween('price',[$data['from'], $data['to']])
                 ->get();
```

Note:-  $data['from'] start value i.e 1 and $data['to'] end value i.e 150 or more

Comment: May be this will help you:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26082523/4248328

Comment: You said that it worked between 1 to 100 but it doesn't work with 150 as max value? Is that correct?

Comment: if you set value 1 to 150 then what is the output of your code?

Comment: it gives me no result that is in between 1 to 100 when i set price 1 to 150

Comment: Did you try hard-coding "1" and "150" on your code?

Comment: No Ronald. I have implement Price range jquery ui . When i get the values successfully of price range. But i don't know why its giving me wrong result

Comment: Try harcoding it first then let's see the results. If results showed up then there must be something wrong when passing the price range.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to isolate the problem.

Comment: u mean i give static values in the code for testing

Comment: @kunal, yes. Put in the static values for testing.

Comment: yes i already tested i gives me wrong result :(

Comment: it gives me only one result that is in between 101-150 , but i set the value 1-150 static

Comment: Here i found the problem. The problem is not in our code the problem is i have taken datatype varchar so its give wrong result now i changed it to int its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. When the data type of the value is not an integer, it will behave very unpredictably. So the solution is to either change the datatype of the column or cast it while fetching, like this:

```php
$from = $data['from'];
$to = $data['to'];

$products = Product::with("productimages")
    ->whereRaw("CAST(price AS UNSIGNED) BETWEEN ${from} AND ${to}")
    ->get();
```

I actually had this issue on the PostgreSQL jsonb data type, as it always returns nested values as strings, and between fetching doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using Where Between

```
$projects = Product::where('created_at', '>', $data['from'])
->where('created_at', '<', $data['to'])    
->get();
```

**OR**

```
  $current = Product::with("productimages")
  ->whereBetween('created_at', array($data['from'], $data['to']))->get();
```

**OR**

```
       DB::table('Product')->whereBetween('created_at', array($data['from'], $data['to']))->get();
```

Comment: Downvoted for no explanation why your solution should work. Also, only the first example is actually different.