# Laravel: Get models where between two dates in this week

Tags: php, laravel, date, eloquent, where-clause

I have an eloquent model where i got two columns 'startdate' and 'enddate'. I wanna display all the models that are ongoing in the current week, i.e. any date between 'startdate' and 'enddate' that matches any date of the current week.
I first tried to get by only using the startdate like this:

```
$startOfWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->startOfDay();
$endOfWeek = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->endOfDay();

$modelThisWeek = Model::whereBetween('startdate', [$startOfWeek, $endOfWeek])->get();
```

But naturally, anything that started more than a week ago, but is still ongoing ('enddate' is not finished yet) won't show up.

How could i get all the models valid for the current week efficiently?

Edit: So what I kinda want to do (sounds stupid now) is to get all the dates in between 'startdate' and 'enddate' like in an array for example, get a second array of all dates in between the current week and use like an array_intersect and get those models. I hope I explained that a bit more clearly this time.

Edit 2: Some sample data and expected result.

Data in DB:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | some_other_col | startdate  | enddate      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | ...            | 12. Jan 17 | 20. Feb 17   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | ...            | 12. Jan 17 | 18. Jan 17   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | ...            | 30. Jan 17 | 04. Feb 17   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | ...            | 04. Feb 17 | 07. Feb 17   |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5  | ...            | 08. Feb 17 | 10. Feb 17   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

So if I want all the models within the current week:
29. Jan 17 - 05. Feb 17

I expect the models with the ID 1, 3, 4;
Like all the models that are ongoing within the two dates (startOfWeek and endOfWeek).

Comment: Can you call `whereBetween` 2 times like `Model::whereBetween()->whereBetween()->get()`?

Comment: You can do that, but i'd only get the models with the startdate in this week and the enddate in this week. What if the startdate was like two months ago and the enddate is like in 3 weeks?

Comment: May this helps a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082043/wherebetween-dates-in-laravel-4-eloquent#26082523  i do not use eloquent - seems orWhereBetween can help!?

Comment: That won't do either, on that anwser i'll only get those models where the startdate is inbetween the current week and those models where the enddate is inbetween the current week, but not those models where the startdate and enddate are not in the current week, but the current week is inbetween the startdate and the enddate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is quite simple if you define 2 possible outputs

1. Your model got starting and ending dates
2. Your model got only starting date (ending date is null)

First output you already covered, so only second output need to cover up

Your query should look like for both outputs

```
$modelThisWeek = Model::where(['startdate','>='$startOfWeek],
                              ['enddate','<=', $endOfWeek])
               ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                   $query->where('enddate', '>',  $endOfWeek);
               })
           })->get();
```

It will maybe need some tweaks (I didn't totally understand you if you check for this week and you want in output still ongoing model which may started few weeks ago etc). Try it and if there is any more additional condition feel free to ask.

Comment: yes, i want the models still ongoing, i.e. which started a few weeks ago. There's never a model without and enddate, so the 'orWhere' will never give out something, the first only gives out these with start- and enddate actually in the week.

Comment: @AgashThamo. Check updated answer, i think this should work now

Comment: Sadly no, I edited my question for more clear explanation on what I want to do. There's no model with startdate or enddate = null. It's a required field. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Tell me what is the enddate for models which are still ongoing and replace that value with null in inner where in my query

Comment: I'm so stupid.. you answer is probably correct if i tweak it a bit. All the models which are ongoing will be where the enddate is bigger than the startOfTheWeek variable, easy like that, i think. I just gotta go test it now.

Comment: If you provided some sample data and desired output then i would provide correct query. I just wrote "bacis query" which with little tweaks can do what you need

Comment: Added some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @AgashThamo. Updated my answer, i think it should give you your desired output

Comment: Well, with your input I now got it.. it's very simple, just got blinded from coding all day. I simply want every model where enddate >= $startOfWeek and startdate <= endOfWeek; Simple as that, I'll still mark your aswer as correct though.