# How to Calculate price between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$pro_id = 23;
$room_id = 10;
$start_date = '2022-10-28';
$end_date = '2022-11-03';
```

I failed with this query

```
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, price 
FROM Table 
WHERE `pro_id`= 23 AND rooms_id= 10 AND 
((start_date <= CAST('2022-10-28' AS DATE) AND end_date >= CAST('2022-11-03' AS DATE)) OR
(start_date <= CAST('2022-11-03' AS DATE) AND end_date >= CAST('2022-11-03' AS DATE)) OR
(start_date >= CAST('2022-10-28' AS DATE) AND end_date <= CAST('2022-11-03' AS DATE)))
```

Price Table:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCm8X.png]

```
+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
| id | pro_id  | room | data_start | data_end   | price |
+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
|  1 |      23 |   10 | 2022-10-01 | 2022-10-31 | 35000 |
|  2 |      23 |   10 | 2022-11-01 | 2022-11-30 | 37500 |
+----+---------+------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I want to Output

```
+----+---------+------+-----------+--------------+
| id | pro_id  | room | price     | actual price |
+----+---------+------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |      23 |   10 | 35000 x 4 |     140000   |
|  2 |      23 |   10 | 37500 x 3 |     112500   |
+----+---------+------+-----------+--------------+
```

if I book a room from **'2022-10-28'** to **'2022-11-03'** for 7 nights then the price will count as **35000 x 4** and **37500 x 3**

like 2022-10-28, 29, 30, 31 = 35000 and 2022-11-01, 02, 03 = 37500

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Try `whereBetween` query  for Dates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26082523/5192105

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi whereBetween is Laravel eloquent not pure sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer from StackOverflow to another question

```html
SELECT   propertie_id, rooms_id,
         SUM(price * (1 + DATEDIFF(
              LEAST(end_date,   '2022-11-03' - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
           GREATEST(start_date, '2022-10-28')
         ))) AS Total
FROM     vi_properties_price_season_wise
WHERE   propertie_id = 23 AND rooms_id = 10 AND (
              '2022-11-03' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                           BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
           OR '2022-10-28' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
         )
GROUP BY propertie_id, rooms_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would suggest doing it on PHP side.

```
$conn = $em->getConnection();

$pro_id = 23;
$room_id = 10;
$start_date = new \DateTime('2022-10-28');
$end_date = new \DateTime('2022-11-03');

$result = [];

//loop through each day
$currentDate = $start_date;
while ($currentDate <= $end_date) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, pro_id, room, price FROM Table WHERE pro_id = ? AND room = ? AND CAST(? AS DATE) BETWEEN start_date and end_date";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $pro_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $room_id);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $currentDate->format('Y-m-d'));
    $data = $stmt->executeQuery()->fetchAssociative();

    // check here if $data IS NOT EMPTY

    if (array_key_exists($data['id'], $result)) {
        ++$result[$data['id']]['dates'];
        $result[$data['id']]['actual_price'] = $result[$data['id']]['price'] * $result[$data['id']]['dates'];
    } else {
        $result[$data['id']] = $data;
        $result[$data['id']]['dates'] = 1;
        $result[$data['id']]['actual_price'] = $data['price'];
    }

    $currentDate = $currentDate->add(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
}
```

I used Doctrine ORM connection to test it out on my side. You can query as you wish.

The result array will look like this:

```
var_export($result);

array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'pro_id' => 23,
        'room' => 10,
        'price' => 35000,
        'dates' => 4,
        'actual_price' => 140000,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'pro_id' => 23,
        'room' => 10,
        'price' => 37500,
        'dates' => 3,
        'actual_price' => 112500,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date field data into days, then subtract them, and multiply with price.
Try it:

```
SELECT
pro_id, room, 
price, datediff(start_date, end_date) * price as actual_price
FROM TableName
WHERE 
(
start_date <= CAST('2022-10-28' AS DATE) 
AND
end_date >= CAST('2022-11-03' AS DATE)
)
```

Comment: but this query return nothing